# Finding the Anti-derivative

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I find the anti derivative of the following integral?

$\int$ $(2x+5)^2\,dx$

Wolfram is telling me $\frac{4x^3}{3}$ + $10x^2$ + $25x$.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you mean

$$\int (2x+5)^2\,dx$$

If you learned substitution, you can do a substitution $u=2x+5$. Otherwise

$$(2x+5)^2=(2x+5)(2x+5)=??$$

Comment: ok, so letting $u =2x+5$, I will have $\frac{du}{dx} $2x.   this will give me $du$ = $2dx$ ?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: ok, and this is where I hit a wall. how would I go about putting $du$ = $2dx$ back into $\int u^2$ , if i let $u$ = $2x+5$

Answer (score 3):

Another way to solve it:

\begin{align*} 
\displaystyle \int (2x+5)^2\, \mathrm{d}x & =\int (4x^2+20x+25)\, \mathrm{d}x \\ 
& = 4\int x^2\, \mathrm{d}x+20 \int x\, \mathrm{d}x+\int 25\, \mathrm{d}x \\ 
& =\dfrac{4x^3}{3}+10x^2+25x+\dfrac{125}{6}+\mathscr{C} \\ 
& =\dfrac{4x^3}{3}+10x^2+25x+\mathscr{C}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Where does the $10$ come from, and why did you place $\int$ before all the $x$'s in $4$, and $10$, but after $25$?

Comment: See [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity_of_integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity_of_integration)

Comment: $\displaystyle \int x\, \mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\mathscr{C}$ which implies that $\displaystyle 20 \int x\, \mathrm{d}x=10x^2+\mathscr{C}$

Comment: well, if i were to tackle this using substitution, i am to let $u$ = $2x+5^2$. i know that $\frac{du}{dx} 2$ then i solve for $du$ to get $du$ = $2dx$. so i have $\int u^2\$ , now how do i go about plugging $du$ = $2dx$ back into $\int u^2$ ?

Comment: can you please explain to me how i would tackle this using substitution from the stage $du = 2dx$ back into $\int u^2$ ?

Answer (score 2):

We have

$\begin{align*} 
\displaystyle \int (2x+5)^2\, \mathrm{d}x & =\dfrac{1}{2}\int (2x+5)'(2x+5)^2\, \mathrm{d}x \\ 
& = \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot \dfrac{(2x+5)^3}{3}+\mathscr{C} \\ 
& =\dfrac{4x^3}{3}+10x^2+25x+\dfrac{125}{6}+\mathscr{C} \\ 
& =\dfrac{4x^3}{3}+10x^2+25x+\mathscr{C},
\end{align*}
$

because $\mathscr{C}+\mathscr{C}=\mathscr{C}$.

Comment: well, using substitution I can get it down to $du$ = $2dx$  by letting $u$ = $2x+5$ how would i plug that back into  $\int u^2$

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you're grasping the method of substitution.  Let's say we wish to make the substitution $u=2x+5$.  Taking the derivative yields $\frac{du}{dx}=2$ or $du=2dx$.  Let's start by rewriting the integral as

$$\int\frac12(2x+5)^2(2dx)=\int\frac12u^2du$$

Once you solve this integral, resubstitute $u=2x+5$ to get your answer in terms of $x$.

Comment: where does the $\frac{1}{2}$ come from?

Comment: @KyleH I multipied by both $\frac12$ and $2$.  The product of these is $1$, so the value doesn't change.  Then I simply changed the order of the multiplication so $du$ stands out.